# Android notification Firebase Cloud

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, background-foreground

I have an application with Android Studio and a cellphone with Android 9,  I use firebase cloud messaging too.

When to send a message, arrive to phone, but if the app it's sleep in background not opening the activity only the MainActivity.

I have that implementations:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
```

And this is my Java code on Android

```
private final String ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID ="admin_channel";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int notificationID = new Random().nextInt(3000);

  /*
    Apps targeting SDK 26 or above (Android O) must implement notification channels and add its notifications
    to at least one of them. Therefore, confirm if version is Oreo or higher, then setup notification channel
  */
  System.out.println("Sdk " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
    Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = null;
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK );
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri notificationSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        //setupChannels(notificationManager);
        CharSequence name = "New notification";
        String description = "Device to devie notification";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this, ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logopqno)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notificationSoundUri)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(false)
                .setChannelId(ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    } else {
        notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this, ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logopqno)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notificationSoundUri)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(false)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    }
    //Set notification color to match your app color template
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        notificationBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }
    notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notificationBuilder.build());
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void setupChannels(NotificationManager notificationManager){
    CharSequence adminChannelName = "New notification";
    String adminChannelDescription = "Device to devie notification";

    NotificationChannel adminChannel;
    adminChannel = new NotificationChannel(ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID,
            adminChannelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    adminChannel.setDescription(adminChannelDescription);
    adminChannel.enableLights(true);
    adminChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    adminChannel.enableVibration(true);
    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(adminChannel);
    }
}
```

This is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.machinecare.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <!-- Added by @BM since 08 2019 Nov -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".notification.DashboardActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dashboard"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".notification.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".notification.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You want to open the activity when on receiving the notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FCM set Click_action to activity you want to open.

```
{
"to": "some_device_token",
"content_available": true,
"notification": {
    "title": "hello",
    "body": "yo",
    "click_action": "Notification_activity" // for intent filter in your activity
},

"data": {
    "extra": "juice"
}
```

Add intent-filter in Manifest.xml

Comment: How add the intent-filter in the Manifest?  I'm sorry but I new in mobile I don't understand yet so much

Comment: <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="Notification_activity" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>